# iOS web apps and in-app php linking

Tags: php, html, ajax, ios, web-applications

I'm trying to build a web app to handle guest lists for an event. It's basicly a long list of names, but then I want to be able to click a name and get some info in a sidebar.

My normal aproach is to do some `?id=25` for example, and just load the appropriate info based on that.

But when making such links for the guests, I get kicked out of the app and Safari opens up the link. Do I have to use Ajax, or is there some way to make links work within the app, since it's just an index.php file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an ios app coder, but if you're writing an app, why use urls? 
Why no listen to the events and pull the ID from the clicked user and send the request with the app and then display the content in the sidebar. Sorta like ajax in webapps.

Comment: Because I can't figure out some other way to deal with database calls. Well, wasn't that Ajax you just described?

Comment: Yes it is ajax, just thinking of the equivalent for ios. My advice, append the id to the username in someway. Make a page on the server to serve you user info based on IDs and use ajax to get the content. Else I'm guessing safari is the default handler of urls so it will keep pulling them out.

Answer (score 0):

You should override

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)r navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

by verifying

```
navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked
```

Refer - http://inchoo.net/mobile-development/iphone-development/how-to-override-uiwebview-links-request-action-with-your-own-custom-method/